# Acts_as_paranoid and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using rails 3 and acts_as_paranoid.  I want to make sure that every task has a comment.

How can I bypass this one validation (check_if_notes) if mark_completed_and_msg is called?

EDIT - Is this the right way?

task.rb

```
has_one :comment, :as => :commentable

attr_accessor :force_task

# original was - before_update, :check_if_notes
validate :check_if_notes, :on => :update, :unless => proc { |a| a.force_task }

def mark_completed_and_msg(user_id, msg)
   Comment.create!(:commentable_type => self.class, :commentable_id => self.id, :content => msg )
   self.update_attributes(:completed_by => user_id, :deleted_at => Time.now, :force_task => true)
end

def check_if_notes
  if self.comment.blank? || self.comment.content.blank? || self.comment.content.scan(/[\w-]+/).size <= 2
    saved = false
    self.comment.errors[:content] << "You must have a comment and more than 3 words."
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you meant using `==` in your Proc.

```
:unless => proc { |a| a[:force_task] == true }
```

You can also use

```
:unless => proc { |a| a.force_task? }
```

Comment: You where right, that is the correct way.  Now I'm getting errors again.  If I use { |a| a[:force_task] == true} it does the validation.  if i use { |a| a.force_task? } i get undefined method `force_task?.  Can I pass the force_task if I use update_attributes?  what am I missing?

Comment: That was probably my mistake. Isn't force_task a boolean attribute on your model? Does this work? `{ |a| a.force_task }`

Comment: yep, at the end what worked was :unless => proc { |a| a.force_task }.  Thank you for your help.